# Functor instance for datatype containing function

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have a datatype defined as

```
data Foo a = Foo a (a -> a)
```

The `Foo` data constructor has two parameter value and function. I need to write Monad and Monad transform instance for this.

I am trying to implement functor instance,

```
instance Functor Foo where 
  fmap f (Foo x g) = Foo (f x) (g .(f x))
```

but I got an error `Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’`.

This is correct because `g` only accepts of type `a` and `f x` will convert `a->b` .So next I rewrote as

```
instance Functor Foo where 
  fmap f (Foo x g) = Foo (f x) g
```

I got the same error "Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’".

I also tried this

```
instance Functor Foo where 
  fmap f (Foo x g) = Foo (f x) (f. g x)
```

I got `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ b -> a`  for `(g.x)`

I am stuck, I know function `g` only accepts of type `a` and returns type `a`. but `fmap` will convert type `a` to type `b`. I think I have to apply `fmap` over `g` as well,  which I am not able to do.

How do I write the instance for the above datatype?

Comment: You can't since the result should be a `Foo b (b -> b)`, but you never transform `b` to `a`, hence you can not use the `a -> a` of the original `Foo` to construct a function `b -> b`. Except for the `id` function (i.e. `foo (f x) id`), you can not `fmap` it, but likely that will not hold with the functor laws.

Comment: Thank you. This was given as an assignment for the course I took. I will discuss this question with my tutor. Maybe the question has an typo or incorrect.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Could you please help me understand why do I get "cannot construct the infinite type" for "g x" ?

Comment: @RavitejuaSutrave: because it expects `g x` should then have type `b -> a`, but it has type `a`, if `b -> a` is the same type as `a` then this would result in an infinite recursive type `b -> (b -> (b -> ...)))`.

Comment: Note that you _can_ in fact write a mapping function for this type, just not `fmap`: it would have to have type signature `foomap :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> Foo a -> Foo b`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us take the types into account, we basically need to convert a `Foo a` to a `Foo b`, that means we need to find, given a function `a -> b`, an element of type `a` and a function with type `a -> a`, an element of type `b` and a function of type `b -> b`.

Especially the last is difficult, since we are only given a function with type `a -> b`, and not a function with type `b -> a`, we can not first convert the input to a `a`, then process it through the orignal function and then map it back to a `b`.

It is not entirely impossible to make a mapping that satisfies the types, for example:

```
fmap1 f (Foo x g) = Foo (f x) (const (f x))
```

or:

```
fmap2 f (Foo x g) = Foo (f x) id
```

But the problem with `fmap1` and `fmap2` need to satisfy the law:

```
fmap id = id
```

In other words `fmap id (Foo x g)` needs to be equal to `Foo x g`, now if we use `id` or `const (f x)`, then `id` and `f x` are not always equal to `g`, at least not if `g` is a function that can take any form.

If you of course consider `Foo x g` and `Foo x (id x)` for example to be equivalent, which might be reasonable in some cases as [@leftaroundabout says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65726929/functor-instance-for-datatype-containing-function/65727198?noredirect=1#comment116210744_65727198), then you can implement this as a functor instance.

Comment: IMO it can be ok to have a `fmap` change the actual data structure, as long as the constructors are “private” to the module and none of the exported function allow observing the difference. But that doesn't really help in this example.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: yes, or in case there are preconditions on the shape of the function.

Comment: But can the `(a -> a)` in Foo be anything other than `id`?

Comment: Answering my own question: it can also be `const a`.

Comment: @pedrofurla That's not correct, it can be all sorts of things. The caller who provides the `a -> a` function also gets to decide what `a` is. For example, they could pick `Integer`, and then `(+1)` is a valid function of the correct type. The logic about `id` being the only function of type `a -> a -> a` applies when you have to *supply* a function (and somebody else gets to instantiate the type variable). Not when you are given a function (unless you get to instantiate the type variable).